# Boost.Asio SSL error on HTTP request with error message "http request"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a standard boost.asio http(s) server. If I try and send an http request to this server the async_handshake method always reports error code value `336130204` and error message `http request`. This is great because it allows me to switch to http. My problem is I cant seem to find where/how that error code value is being generated. Im basically trying to avoid doing something like:

```
if (ec.value() == 336130204)
  // Do http
else
  // Do https
```

and instead have something more portable like:

```
if (ec.value() == boost::asio::ssl::error::http_request)
  // Do http
else
  // Do https
```

Am I missing something or does boost somehow mangle the value making it impossible to do something more portable?

Note: I am not using beast and the project I am working on is unable to use this package.

Comment: If things seem "somehow mangled" then 99% of the time you have [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) elsewhere. If you share a self-contained example, then we can tell you what might be wrong.

Comment: I know you don't use beast, but perhaps the documentation about "Detecting SSL" still helps you https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/writing_composed_operations/detect_ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how that value is being generated. The error is coming from openssl and if you look at the `ERR_reason_error_string` function in openssl they use `ERR_GET_LIB(value)` and `ERR_GET_REASON(value)` to reconstruct the value without the function portion. So to properly compare if the response was http request you would do something like:

```
stream_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server,
      [this, self=shared_from_this()](const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
      if (ERR_PACK(ERR_LIB_SSL, ERR_GET_FUNC(ec.value()), SSL_R_HTTP_REQUEST) == ec.value())
      {
        // do http work
      }
      else
      {
        // handle error as usual
      }
});
```

`ERR_PACK` seems to pack the library, function, and reason into one unsigned long integer. `ERR_GET_FUNC` grabs the function value from the unsigned long. `SSL_R_HTTP_REQUEST` is the reason for the error generated by openssl.